# Принадлежность точки прямой в трехмерном пространстве

Tags: c, алгоритм, математика, геометрия

Есть структура описывающая прямую

```
typedef struct line
{
    coord m;//координаты первой точки прямой
    coord n;//координаты второй точки прямой
    coord v;//координаты направляющего вектора

} Line;
```

Я написал проверку на принадлежность, но при определенных тестовых данных она не работает(если ввести одну и туже точку), т.к возникает деление на 0. Я просматривал вопросы на сайте для двумерного пространства, но их решение не подходит.

```
int isBelong(Line l, coord p)
{
    coord t;
    t.x = (l.v.x / (p.x - l.m.x));
    t.y = (l.v.y / (p.y - l.m.y));
    t.z = (l.v.z / (p.z - l.m.z));
    return (t.x == t.y) && (t.y == t.z) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Как можно модифицировать функции, чтобы она работа для всех данных?

Comment: Разве для задания прямой не достаточно двух точек **или** одного направляющего вектора?

Comment: Скажем так, такая структура необходима именно для моей задачи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как идея - если есть две точки `A` и `B`, определяющие прямую, и точка `C`, то эта точка лежит на прямой `AB`, если `|AC| + |BC| == |AB|` или `|AC| + |AB| == |BC|` или `|AB| + |BC| == |AC|` (в зависимости от взаимного расположения точек).

Ну, а расстояние типа `|AC|` по теореме Пифагора находится без всякого деления...

Или посчитать `|AC|`, `|BC|` и `|AB|` и найти площадь треугольника (а лучше ее квадрат - легче) по формуле Герона. Если нуль - значит, все три точки на одной прямой.

Впрочем, это одно и то же :) - ведь первые три равенства проверить можно легко как  равно ли нулю выражение `(|AC| + |BC| - |AB|)*(|AC| + |AB| - |BC|)*(|AB| + |BC| - |AC|)` (что эквивалентно проверке, равна ли нулю площадь по формуле Герона).

Comment: Сейчас попробую реализовать

Comment: Только учтите, что со сравнением `==` у чисел с плавающей точкой несколько грустно, и надо допускать небольшие отклонения (строго сравнивать их нельзя).

Comment: Вроде работает как надо. Я еще несколько тестов проведу и отпишусь

Comment: А куда ж оно денется...

Comment: А если прямая задана параметрически, все равно лучше использовать этот метод или есть другой способ?

Comment: Ну, можно и так, а найти параметр для одной координаты и проверить выполнение для остальных. Если эта координата не изменяется и не равна координате точки - уже понятно, что она не лежит на прямой. Но хоть одна координата да будет меняться - иначе это не прямая, а точка, вот по ней и ищем совпадение, по другим проверяем.

Comment: А можно небольшой пример?

Comment: Ну параметрически x=ax*t+bx, y = ay*t+by... Так? Наша точка - (x0,y0,z0). Приравниваем, скажем, ax*t+bx = x0. Если ax==0, то если bx != x0 - не лежит, если bx==x0 - переходим к следующей переменной. Если ax не нуль - t = (x0-bx)/ax, подставляем в другие уравнения и сравниваем вычисленные y и z с y0 и z0...

Comment: Кажется понял, спасибо)

Comment: Ну, если все проблемы решены - то закрывайте вопрос, помечая ответ как принятый.

Answer (score 0):

Избавиться от деления можно, перегруппировав выражения так:

```
  l.v.x * (p.y - l.m.y) - (p.x - l.m.x) * l.v.y == 0  &&
  l.v.y * (p.z - l.m.z) - (p.y - l.m.y) * l.v.z == 0  &&
  l.v.z * (p.x - l.m.x) - (p.z - l.m.z) * l.v.x == 0;
```

По сути это означает:  каждый компонент векторного произведения равен нулю.

Для вещественных координат можно также проверять, что сумма абсолютных  значений этих компонентов не превышает некой погрешности.

---

Общий случай с учётом погрешностей вещественной арифметики:

В двумерном случае наиболее выгодный вариант - использование векторного произведения. В трёхмерном случае векторное произведение требует заметно больше операций, и лучше использовать подход на основе скалярного произведения.

Имеются векторы **v** - направляющий вектор прямой и **w = p - m**-  вектор из базовой точки прямой на точку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вектор из **m** до проекции точки **p** на прямую

```
pl = v * Dot(w, v) / Dot(v, v)
```

Вектор проекции

```
 pr = p - pl
 len =  |pr|
```

его длина len для точки на прямой нулевая, в реальных вычислениях с плавающей точкой нужно учитывать небольшой допуск. Лучше использовать квадрат расстояния

```
 Dot(pr, pr) < eps^2
```

чтобы корень не извлекать